# Deconstruction in a LINQ select expression

Tags: c#

Given an object with a `Deconstruct` method like the following:

```cs
record Point(int X, int Y);

var point = new Point(1, 2);
var (x, y) = point;

Console.WriteLine(x); // 1
Console.WriteLine(y); // 2
```

Is it possible to deconstruct the object's values in a LINQ select statement?

For example rather than:

```cs
points.Select(p => p.X + p.Y)
```

this

```cs
// CS0019 Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UserQuery.Point' and 'int'
points.Select((x, y) => x + y)
```

This causes a compilation error as it's using the `Select` method overload that takes a `Func<Point, int>`

Comment: You mean? `p => { var (x, y) = p; return x+y; }`

Comment: i cannot even compile you first code snippet using vs2022, .net 6 project. why?

Comment: See also https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/258

Comment: why you don't like the `points.Select(p => p.X + p.Y)` query?

However the `points.Select((x, y) => x + y)` rise an error due to the `x` correspond to the point and the `y` is the index of this point into the `points` list.

Answer (score 7):

Here is how I would do it without the extension method, as long as my point object can be deconstructed as shown in your question, I can do the following:

```
points.Select(p =>
{
    // deconstruct each element of the object
    var (x, y) = p;
    return x + y;
});
```

in one line

```
points.Select(p => { var (x, y) = p; return x + y; });
```

I hope it can solve your question

Answer (score 3):

In the default library `Select` extension method allows being used by `IEnumerable` collection objects.

The method signature looks like below.

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector);
```

If you want to deconstruction as select expression you can try to write your custom `Select` extension method.

```
public static class PointExt
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Select<T>(this IEnumerable<Point> points, Func<int, int, T> selector)
    {
        foreach (var p in points)
        {
            yield return selector(p.X, p.Y);
        }
    }

    public static T Select<T>(this Point p, Func<int, int, T> selector)
    {
        return selector(p.X, p.Y);
    }
}
```

Then it can use as this code snippet.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var point = new Point(1, 2);
    List<Point> points = new List<Point>(){ point };
    var res = points.Select((x, y) => x + y);
    Console.WriteLine(res.First());
    Console.WriteLine(point.Select((x, y) => x + y));
}
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IVD2Xc)

Comment: will this type of extension go to stadard(built in) linq, since it looks quite natural?

Comment: @Lei It probably won't, for the same reasons that [`Deconstruct` wasn't implemented through an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46405775/c-sharp-7-why-is-tuple-deconstruction-not-implemented-through-an-interface). Custom extension provides the most flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box, no, what you're asking isn't possible.

There is more than one reason.

#### Reason #1

By default, there's an `Enumerable.Select` method that has two parameters. One of Type T (the enumerable member) and one of type int (the index).
This reason is why you receive:

```
// CS0019 Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UserQuery.Point' and 'int'
```

#### Reason #2

The second reason this isn't possible is the notion of deconstruction doesn't apply to parameter creation.

For instance:

```
var (x, y) = myPoint;
```

Is different than the lambda syntax of:

```
var myPointSumQuery = myPoints.Select((x, y) => x + y);
```

#### Conclusion

There's no built-in way for the compiler to know 'Hey they want to deconstuct this enumerable series into parameters'.

You get close with the following:

```
var p = new Point(3, 3);
var p2 = new[] { p };
var p3 = p2.Select(x => (x.X, x.Y)).Select(((int x, int y) e) => e.x + e.y);
```

But if you notice, you end up with the same problem of X and Y needing to be contained within the parameter 'e'.

There was discussion along these lines which would get you closer if you see the following link: [Proposal: Tuple deconstruction in lambda argument list](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/258)

It seems that it was never implemented, because this is illegal:

```
var p3 = p2.Select(x => (x.X, x.Y)).Select(((int x, int y)) => x + y);
```

Since C# cannot deconstruct tuples into parameters, the extended notion of 'Deconstruct the each point's members into parameters' would not work, either.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can create some extension method for point, which looks similar to Select in LINQ.

```
public static class PointExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TResult>(this IEnumerable<Point> source, Func<int, int, TResult> selector)
    {
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            yield return selector(item.X, item.Y);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can call the extension method as you mentioned.
points.Select((x, y) => x + y)